# expansion of \settowidth in macro definition

Tags: expansion

Why does the footnote come out as nr. 2 in the MWE below? I guess it may have to do something with expansion inside the `\foofoo` macro definition. I'd be very glad for any explanation about the process going on there and how to avoid the footnote coming out as nr. 2 instead of the expected nr. 1.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newlength{\mylength}
\newcommand{\foofoo}[2]{%
\settowidth{\mylength}{#1}#1\hspace{\mylength}#2}


\begin{document}


\foofoo{foo\footnote{A foobar note.}}{bar}


\end{document}
```

Comment: I probably would not call this an expansion issue (in the sense that other TeX problems are expansion issues). The problem is that `#1` is executed twice: Once to measure its length with `\settowidth` and then again to typeset it. So `\footnote` gets called twice. The first `\footnote` only steps up the counter and the actual note is lost, but the second `\footnote` steps up the counter again and lands at the bottom of the page.

Comment: I see. Many thanks for explaining that mechanism.